# Trying to add virtual property to query result in Symfony2 with JMS

Tags: symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle

I have a simple task ahead of me, yet I find myself pretty much incapable of completing it.
My model is pretty complex, so I'll try to simplify for the sake of being specific.

I have two entities, Call and Caller, with entity repositories that I access via custom services. I am using JMS Serializer Bundle. All entities are mapped correctly, the the whole thing is working pretty fine. But I have this idea that I just can't make happen. To the point...
These are my entities described:

```
--Call--
#call_id
location
date_created
Caller

--Caller--
#caller_id
phone_num
```

The idea is to have a list of all calls with their fields for example:

```
New York, 2015.12.12. 20:07:06, Novak Djokovic, 3816976548 [YY]
London, 2015.12.13. 20:07:06, Jelena Jankovic, 3811116333 [XX]
```

Fields YY and XX represent the number of calls already in a database with that specific number.

I have a query that returns the list without YY and XX values, and I also have a separate query that returns number of calls from a specific number. The thing gets complicated when I try to join them. Not sure how to do that.

I read about VirtualProperty annotation for JMS, but failed to actually see how to use it this time (since it's not a good practice to access your repository or service from an Entity).

These are my methods:

## 1 - get list of all calls with callers

```
public function findAllCalls()
    {
        $callerAlias = "c";

        //getAlias method returns the alias of the current entity (call)
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->getAlias());
        $qb->leftJoin($this->getAlias() . '.caller', $callerAlias);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

## 2 - get number of calls from a specific number based on a call as a parameter

```
public function getNumberOfCalls(Call $call) {

        $callerAlias = "c";

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->getAlias());
        $qb->leftJoin($this->getAlias() . '.caller', $callerAlias);
        $qb->select("COUNT(" . $this->getAlias() . ".call_id)");
        $qb->where($callerAlias.".phonenbr = ".$call->getPhoneNumber());

        return $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
    }
```

Hoping to hear your opinions on this, 'cause I really struggled to find the sollution.